# Batch IF doesn't work

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I made a simple BATCH file for notes, it just deletes a folder, makes a new one, and puts in a file called note.txt and then edits it... for some reason, it doesn't do ANYTHING at all! not even removing the folder, here's the code:

```
goto start
:abort
        ECHO Aborted!
        PAUSE
        GOTO start

:replace
        del /q "D:\Users\Eldar\Desktop\Note Folder"
        mkdir "Note Folder"
        @echo>"D:\Users\Eldar\Desktop\Note Folder\note.txt"
        @echo %note%> "D:\Users\Eldar\Desktop\Note Folder\note.txt"
        pause

:start
    @ECHO OFF
    color e
    cls
    echo Put the note in here:
    set /p LastNote=<"D:\Users\Eldar\Desktop\Note Folder\note.txt"
    SET /P note=
    cls
    echo Note has been saved!
    echo also, the last note you saved was: "%LastNote%".
    echo so are you sure you want to replace this note with a new one (Y/N)?
    SET /P agree=
    IF "%agree%"=="y" (
         ECHO goto replace
    ) ELSE (
        GOTO abort
    )
```

Comment: `Del` is for files, use `RD` for directories/folders, type `RD /?` for help with that

Comment: Consider using the [`choice`](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command for Yes/No questions. It does the input validation for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few errors in your script:

1. `del` can delete only empty folders. Use `rmdir /s /q folder_name` to remove folder with files
2. Remove `ECHO` in `ECHO goto replace`
3. You are using full paths everywhere except `mkdir`. Is it correct?

My working version:

```
@echo off

goto start

:abort
    echo Aborted!
    pause
    goto start

:replace
    rmdir /s /q ".\TestF"
    mkdir "TestF"
    echo>".\TestF\note.txt"
    echo %note%> ".\TestF\note.txt"
    pause

:start
    color e
    cls
    echo Put the note in here:
    set /p LastNote=<".\TestF\note.txt"
    set /p note=
    cls
    echo Note has been saved!
    echo also, the last note you saved was: "%LastNote%".
    echo so are you sure you want to replace this note with a new one (Y/N)?
    set /p agree=
    if "%agree%"=="y" (
        goto replace
    ) else (
        goto abort
    )
```

Comment: yes, the file is located at the same place the folder should be located in, that's why I do not use the path.

Comment: And the ECHO is a part of an attempt to copy a sample of IF from the network (I thought my IF statement is wrong) so I forgot to remove the ECHO because in the sample it had IF statement (ECHO FOUND)...

Comment: I know, I **thought** its the if, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no reason to remove the `Note Folder` directory or even to delete the `note.txt` file.

How does it perform if you rewrite it like this?

```bat
@Echo Off
Color 0E

Set "LastNote="
If Exist "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Note Folder\note.txt" (
    Set/P LastNote=<"%UserProfile%\Desktop\Note Folder\note.txt"
)
If Not Defined LastNote GoTo replace

:ask
    ClS
    Echo=The last note you saved was:
    Echo=%LastNote%
    Echo=
    Choice /M "Would you like to replace this note with a new one"
    If "%ErrorLevel%"=="1" GoTo replace
    Echo=
    Echo=Aborted!
    Timeout -1
    GoTo ask

:replace
    ClS
    Set/P "note=Put the note in here: "
    If "%note%"=="" GoTo ask
    Echo=Note has been saved!
    If Not Exist "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Note Folder\" (
        MD "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Note Folder"
    )
    (Echo=%note%)>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\Note Folder\note.txt"
    Timeout -1
    GoTo ask
```

For the benefit of the OP, here is your version of your script with the major flaws removed and with unnecessary lines kept in.

```bat
@goto start
:abort
    ECHO Aborted!
    PAUSE
    GOTO start

:replace
    rmdir "D:\Users\Eldar\Desktop\Note Folder"
    mkdir "D:\Users\Eldar\Desktop\Note Folder"
    echo.>"D:\Users\Eldar\Desktop\Note Folder\note.txt"
    >"D:\Users\Eldar\Desktop\Note Folder\note.txt" echo %note%
    pause

:start
    @ECHO OFF
    color e
    cls
    echo Put the note in here:
    set /p LastNote=<"D:\Users\Eldar\Desktop\Note Folder\note.txt"
    SET /P note=
    cls
    echo Note has been saved!
    echo also, the last note you saved was: "%LastNote%".
    echo so are you sure you want to replace this note with a new one (Y/N)?
    SET /P agree=
    IF "%agree%"=="y" (
        goto replace
    ) ELSE (
        GOTO abort
    )
```

Comment: The file doesn't need deleting because it is overwritten with the new content by default. :ask makes more sense than :start because it isn't at the start, change it back if you want. _It's you asking for help and using terms such as **wtf** doesn't usually aid you in achieving that_.

Comment: Well, I am too lazy to delete the file itself:3 Also, why do you SET "LastNote=" if then you set it again? I don't need this, I know it exists! I know there's something in the note... and omfg. Listen, I am not trying this code to be efficient, all I needed is it to work, I don't care if choice is a better idea or checking if the file exists or empty is better, because I know it exists and is not empty! Please don't try to "fix" or make things "better" because they're not, there's a reason I put it like this.

Comment: I asked for one tiny thing: Why is my file doesn't work? I didn't ask: "Hello can you help me make this more efficient?" All I asked is why doesn't it work, I got my answer, I don't need more than that!

Comment: The first time the script is ever run, there may be no existing `note.txt` or `Note Folder`. In that case there will be no data in `%LastNote%` and the script will then bypass the code asking about a replacement as there is nothing to replace. It's good coding practice, not an efficiency exercise. If you don't want good coding help go some place else, otherwise please be a little more respectful to those willing to help you.

Comment: I know how to code, but I also know what I am doing, this program was made for ME only, it will NEVER be published, therefore as I know myself, I will not leave an empty Note, and that's exactly why I am deleting and making a new folder. I do not need to check if the chances of a non-existing folder/file are 0%!

Comment: I apologise if I incorrectly assumed that someone who didn't know how `del` worked, or how to use **`/?`** was a competent coder. _(especially with the 'few errors' pointed out by the other person who answered)_. Incidentally that first simple answer/question was first made by myself as a comment, _showing a little less aggression would certainly help you here, moving forward_.

Comment: I have appended a basic example of your original script to my answer which should fix the major flaws. Do with it as you will.